# How to find which program is writing to the C: drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have a problem. The system regularly runs out of space on the C:/ drive. Is there a simple way to take a snapshot of the disk space usage, so that I could free up some space, take this snapshot, wait until the drive fills up again and compare (and then use e.g. Process Monitor to find the responsible program)?

Or find the program writing a lot to C: directly?

Comment: Sounds like you already answered this: use Process Monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify which windows version you are using, but if it is not ancient (e.g. not XP or older) then the easiest way to do this with build in software would be:

1. Start the task manager (e.g. press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> and click on "start task manager").
2. Go to the performance tab.
3. Click on "resource monitor".
4. Once the resource monitor has started, go to the [Disk] tab. It will list current program and how much they read and **write** to the volumes.

[image: Windows 7 task manager example]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [FoldersChangesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html): it is a simple tool that monitors the folder or disk drive that you choose and lists every filename that is being modified, created, or deleted while the folder is being monitored. 
Then, it's also [Treesize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/), a tool to check the size of all folder of your disk,
to find out where is the file that has gone too large.
But, in any case, to be able to see what process is constantly writing to the disk,
Process Monitor is the way to go.